# Call one controller from another in express API

Tags: node.js, express

I have a Node.js Express server serving my API.  I've got a `getHighestPriorityCamera` which goes to the DB and gets the highest priority camera.  I've further got an `updateCamera` which can update a camerea given a camera object and a url paramater.

I need to occasionally get the highest priority camera AND reset the priority at the same time.  Given DRY yourself principles, I'd like to utilize the existing two routes. ... but I don't know how to appropriately call and pass the req/res around.

Functionally, I'd like to call `getHighestPriorityCamera`, take the resulting returned camera object, modify it so the priority is reset to zero, then submit that modified camera object to `updateCamera`.  THEN send the camera object to the original requester.

My controller looks like this:

```
const Camera = require('../models/camera-model')

updateCamera = async (req, res) => {
    const incomingCameraData = req.body;
    if (!incomingCameraData) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            error: 'You must provide a body to update to update camera',
        })
    }

    Camera.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, (err, camera) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                success: false,
                error: err,
                message: 'Camera not found!',
            })
        }

        Object.keys(incomingCameraData).forEach(key => {
            camera[key] = incomingCameraData[key]
        })

        camera.save()
            .then(() => {
                return res.status(200).json({
                    success: true,
                    id: camera._id,
                    message: 'Camera updated!!',
                })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                return res.status(404).json({ success: false, error, message: 'Camera not updated!', })
            })
    })
}


getHighestPriorityCamera = async (req, res) => {
    console.log("Get highest");
    Camera.findOne({ enabled: true }, (err, cam) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: err })
        }
        if (!cam) {
            return res.status(404).json({ success: false, error: `No enabled cameras found to look for highest priority` })
        }
        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: cam })
    })
        .sort({ processingPriority: -1 }) //sort highest to lowest (then 'findOne' grabs the first)
}

getHighestPriorityCameraAndReset = async (req, res) => { 

// ?????
// In an effort to DRY ... would like to call "getHighestPriorityCamera" then, take that result and call "updateCamera", then send result back to original requester

}

module.exports = {
    updateCamera,
    getHighestPriorityCamera,
    getHighestPriorityCameraAndReset,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If both controllers wants to use the same functionality you should extract common code into a separate function and call it from both controllers.

In my opinion all controllers should be independent and don't call each other routes at all.

If all such common functions just operate DB objects then I recommend you to place them into repositories. That way you separate DB layer from others.

Example of a repository:

```
const Camera = require('../models/camera-model')

function getHighestPriorityCamera() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Camera.findOne({ enabled: true }, (err, cam) => {
        if (err) {
            return resolve({ success: false, error: err, status: 400 })
        }
        if (!cam) {
            return resolve({ success: false, error: `No enabled cameras found to look for highest priority`, status: 404 })
        }
        return resolve({ success: true, data: cam })
    }).sort({ processingPriority: -1 }) //sort highest to lowest (then 'findOne' grabs the first)
  })
}

module.exports = {
  getHighestPriorityCamera
}
```

Using repository:

```
const cameryRepository = require('./repositories/camera';

getHighestPriorityCamera = async (req, res) => {
  cameryRepository.getHighestPriorityCamera().then(result => {
    if (result.success) {
      res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: result.data })
    } else {
      res.status(result.status).json({ success: false, error: result.error })
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I'm not following.   The 'common code' is database-driven code.  I can't just extract it into a static helper file.

I want to have an API endpoint that can do X ... and have another api endpoint that does X & Y.   Wouldn't it make sense to have the same code do X rather than repeating?  I mean, I could just copy-and-paste the code from those two functions, but that seems like a bad practice.

If I fundamentally misunderstand, feel free to give a small example?

Comment: added examples to my answer